# Detect how many items an object collided with / negating more than one object

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, cocos2d-js

In creating a small breakout clone using Cocos2d-JS, I've managed to get the ball to bounce whenever it hits a block by negating (or multiplying by -1) either the X or the Y values.

This works, at least until the ball (which is really a small rect with a sprite) manages to hit two blocks at once, at which point either the X or Y values are negated twice.

The ball then proceeds to continue on its path without bouncing, resulting in a very short and very strange Breakout game.

Is there any way to detect how many items have collided with the ball, and to disregard one?

Or is there some other way to do this?

Thanks.

Here's my collision code:

```
if (Tools.rectsIntersect(this, g_Ball)) {
      if (g_Ball.y < this.y || g_Ball.y > this.y) {
          g_Ball.yDirection = g_Ball.yDirection * -1;
      }
      else if (g_Ball.x < this.x || g_Ball.x > this.x) {
          g_Ball.xDirection = g_Ball.xDirection * -1;
      }
      this.destroyBlock();
}


Tools.rectsIntersect = function (obj1, obj2) {box
    var aRect = obj1.collideRect();
    var bRect = obj2.collideRect();
    return cc.rectIntersectsRect(aRect, bRect);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how you're initiating that collision check (I assume you or the engine under the hood are using requestAnimationFrame, or setInterval, and then you're just iterating over every single brick and testing against the ball), it's hard to give you a perfect solution. But assuming that's what you're doing, there's still one design question left. Should a ball be able to hit 2 blocks at once?

```
// if YES:
var allTheBlocks = someListOfAllTheBlocks;
var reflectInX = false;
var reflectInY = false;

for (var i = 0; i < allTheBlocks.length; i++) {
    var thisBlock = allTheBlocks[i];
    if (Tools.rectsIntersect(thisBlock, g_Ball)) {
        if (g_Ball.y < thisBlock.y || g_Ball.y > thisBlock.y) {
            reflectInY = true;
        } else if (g_Ball.x < thisBlock.x || g_Ball.x > thisBlock.x) {
            reflectInX = true;
        }
        thisBlock.destroyBlock();
    }
}

if (reflectInY) {
    g_Ball.yDirection *= -1;
}

if (reflectInX) {
    g_Ball.xDirection *= -1;
}

//=====================
// OR, if NO:
var allTheBlocks = someListOfAllTheBlocks;

for (var i = 0; i < allTheBlocks.length; i++) {
    var thisBlock = allTheBlocks[i];
    if (Tools.rectsIntersect(thisBlock, g_Ball)) {
        if (g_Ball.y < thisBlock.y || g_Ball.y > thisBlock.y) {
            g_Ball.yDirection *= -1;
        } else if (g_Ball.x < thisBlock.x || g_Ball.x > thisBlock.x) {
            g_Ball.xDirection *= -1;
        }
        thisBlock.destroyBlock();
        break;
    }
}
// And then if the ball has traversed too far in that frame, due to lag, or loose math,
// make sure to manually set it's position to be outside of the block it hit. Or if you are
// playing that your ball has some 'flex' to it, then just leave it be.
```

There's obviously optimization that can be done in the collision plus position code, but what's there totally works.

Comment: I used cocos2D's built in cc.rectIntersectsRect function. I'm not entirely sure how it functions, but you had the right idea of putting blocks in an array. I had trouble with the collisions, though, sometimes the direction isn't reversed, though in my initial code, so far, they've all had the directions reversed.